# Sound that's not working Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: sound, alsa, 23.04

The sound on my laptop is not working. I went on this website for help:
https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-no-sound-issue-ubuntu/#pavucontrol and I ran this command: `amixer -D pulse sset Master toggle`.
The ouput is displayed in the image below. I thought that maybe my issue was that [off] that's written right next to "Front Left" and "Front Right". How can I turn it [on]?
Thanks in advance,
Hans

[image]